# JMeter Perfmon Plugin Server Agent error: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Tags: linux, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, server-monitoring

I tried to use Jmeter Perfmon plugin to extract monitoring of CPU and Memory utilisation of Linux server. Server is hosted on Linux machine. Currently I connected to the Linux remotely using MobaXterm Personal Edition v21.2 (via SSH connection), and able to access the Linux machine successfully.

I already installed the [Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent) on the Linux.

Now, I want to change the server agent port number to 22 since the Linux machine is using port 22 using this command `ServerAgent-2.2.3/ServerAgent-2.2.3/startAgent.sh --udp-port 0 --tcp-port 22`. Please refer below error:

[image]

I changed the permission at the server agent file already:

[image]

Wondering why the permission is still denied? Until now I still unable to connect with port 22. If possible, I want to try this solution first before opt to [JMeter SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener). Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I want to change the server agent port number to 22 since the Linux machine is using port 22

this assumption is wrong, you need to start the PerfMon Agent on a **free port**

The reason you're getting the error is trying to run a program which tries to bind to the [privileged port](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) as non-[superuser](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-login-as-super-user/) account. Only `root` can use ports below 1024, normal users are restricted to the ports above 1024.

Even if you switch to root user I don't think you will be able to run PerfMon Agent on port 22 as most probably your [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) server is running there so the port is busy.

So choose a free port above 1024, open it in [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)), run the ServerAgent and most probably you will be able to get the metrics by connecting PerfMon Metrics Collector listener to this host:port combination.

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)